# (Python, sqlite3) Building relational database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, relational

I am trying to create a relational database in python with sqlite3. I am a little fussy on how to connect the tables in the database so that one entity connects to another via the second table. I want to be able to make a search on a persons name via a webpage and then find the parents related to that person. Im not sure if I need two tables or three.

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
class Database:
   '''Initiates the database.'''
   def __init__(self):
      self.db = sqlite3.connect('family2.db')
   def createTable(self):
      r = self.db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS family2 (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
      fname TEXT,
      sname TEXT,
      birthdate TEXT,
      deathdate TEXT,
      mother TEXT,
      father TEXT
      )''')
      self.db.commit()

      g = self.db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parents(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
      mother TEXT,
      father TEXT)''')  
      self.db.commit()

      b = self.db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS relations(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
      family2,      
      parents TEXT
      )''')
      self.db.commit()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple tables; you can store the IDs of the parents in the table itself:

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    mother_id INT,
    father_id INT
);
```

You can then find the mother of a person that is identified by its name with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM persons
WHERE id = (SELECT mother_id
            FROM persons
            WHERE name = '...')
```

Comment: I appreciate the prompt response, but this solution is what I have come up with already. I want to learn about relational databases and thus want two tables in my database.

Comment: Two tables do not make sense when you have only one object type (person).